# Como fazer carousel cycle2 contínuo sem pausa?

Tags: jquery

Estou usando o primeiro exemplo dessa página http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php , mas não quero que tenha essa pausa na transição. Gostaria que ficasse passando as imagens direto, sem pausar. É possível fazer isso ou tenho que escolher outro plugin?

Comment: Tente alterar esse atributo: `data-cycle-timeout=1000`, para 0 ou seja: `data-cycle-timeout=0`. Como ficaria seu código final: `<div class="slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=carousel
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-carousel-visible=5`

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft coloquei 0 e ele ficou travado

Comment: Tente colocar outro valor, como 500 talvez, vai diminuindo até chegar ao valor que te agrade na transição... ou aumentando para ver qual o resultado que ele trás... faça alguns testes :)